# Changing aspect ratio in beamer (feather theme)

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Overleaf has a very nice feather theme for presentations based on the Beamer class. My problem is that when I add the class option `aspectratio=169` the footer line disappears.

[image]

vs.

[image]

The code is available at: https://www.overleaf.com/14738074chdcmxfqympr

Comment: can you please post your code as text and not as screenshots?

Comment: Sure, it uses 4 different style files, so I have provided a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the feather theme seems quite strange. While the text of the footline is inserted via the normal footline template, the blue line is part of the background and placed at a fixed distance from the top of the frame ....

```
\documentclass[10pt,
aspectratio=169
]{beamer}
\usetheme{Feather}

\title{The Feather Beamer Theme}
\subtitle[The Feather Beamer Theme]{v. 1.0.0}
\author[Lilyana Vankova]{Lilyana Vankova}
\institute[]{Faculty of Mathematics, Informatics and Information}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=structure.fg,fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.0\paperwidth,left,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex]{footline}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{3.5ex}%
    \insertshortauthor\ |\ 
    \insertshorttitle
    \insertshortsubtitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]